# git archive from VisualStudioOnline, seems to hang,,

Tags: git, azure-devops

Attempting to just get some localisation XML files from a git repo. Aiming to do this on an automated regular basis.

I've succeeded in generating an SSH key pair, associating the public one with visualstudioonline and loaded my private key into my local authentication agent

I execute the command:

```
git archive --verbose --format=zip --output=/z/a.zip --remote=ssh://user@somedomain.visualstudio.com:22/DefaultCollection/_git/THE_PROJECT master /THE/PATH/TO/WhatIWant/
```

This just hangs. It does create a 0 byte zip file, but it never fills it. It never pumps any messages to the console either, so I'm not sure what it's doing

If I use HTTPS then git fails with "operation not supported by protocol"

-

I note that if I run the command without the --remote switch, and make sure my current directory is inside a cloned version of the repo then it all works out

Does this mean VSO can never create a zip file? Is "git archive" supported on VSO?

Comment: I get the same result (clone remote repository with SSH works fine)

Comment: I caught some blog post saying that the author couldn't connect to VSO via SSH and get a terminal to issue commands, so perhaps they're related. I came back this morning to see several "Connection reset by 12.34.56.78 port 22" messages in the console so I guess the SSH part of the connection is timing out. While I don't think I can propose it as an answer, for future visitors looking to use GIT ARCHIVE as a way to get just a part of their repo, there is a REST API supported by TFS/VSTS that may achieve the same result (you can CURL/WGET a zip archive of part of your repo)

Comment: Documentation for VSTS/TFS REST API is at: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that programmatically through [TFS Extended Client library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) with REST API. So you can create a console application with some parameters to download source files from repository programmatically, then call it from command.

1. Add/install Extended Client package to your project
2. Simple code

:

```
var u = new Uri("https://XXX.visualstudio.com");
                VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential("username", "password")));
                var connection = new VssConnection(u, c);

                var gitServer = connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();
              Stream s=  gitServer.GetItemZipAsync(project:"ScrumGitStarain", repositoryId:"LocalPushTest",path: "/ClassLibrary1").Result;
                using (var fileStream = File.Create(@"D:\t.zip"))
                {
                    s.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }
```